# c++ character input only first letter being output

Tags: c++

im new to c++ and i have no idea why is it only the first letter being output in a character input even if i type 10 characters on it.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
struct studentid
{
    char name[20];
    int age[20];
    double salary[20];

};

int main(){
    int num;
    studentid student;
    cout<<"Enter Number of Student: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"======================" <<endl;

    for(int x=0;x<num;x++){
        cout<<"Student " <<x+1 <<endl;
        cout<<"Enter name: ";
        cin>>student.name[x];
        cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
        cout<<"Enter age: ";
        cin>>student.age[x];
        cout<<"Enter salary: ";
        cin>>student.salary[x];

    }
    for(int x =0;x<num;x++){
        cout<<"========================" <<endl;
        cout<<"Student name: " <<student.name[x] <<endl <<"Student age: "<<student.age[x] <<endl <<"Student salary: "<<student.salary[x] <<endl;
    }
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: I think the *main* problem is that you should really have an array of `studentid` structures, not a structure of arrays. And for the immediate problem, `student.name[x]` is a single character, try e.g . `char name[20][20]` instead.

Comment: Try what @Someprogrammerdude is saying make an array of structs `studentid studen[20];` and `student[x].name`

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on the data:

```
struct studentid
{
    char name[20];---> //change this for std::vector<string> name
    int age[20];
    double salary[20];

};
```

`char name[20];` is a array where you can store 20 charachters, so your program will store 1 `char`, 1 `int` and 1 `double` per `studentid`

If you want to store the name, you need to declare name as a array or vector of strings (check the code above).

------EDIT-----

I see you are new on c++ so may be vectors are a bit advance level for you, so you could follow the approach mentioned on the comments. Make a array of structs like this `studentid studen[20];` and change your struct to:

```
struct studentid
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    double salary;

};
```

but be aware, the name must not be more than 19 characters and make sure to set the last char as NULL

Comment: `the name cannot be longer than 20 characters` -> `must not be more than 19 characters and make sure to set the last char as NULL`

Comment: thanks for the reply. i see now how it works, thank you for the details, god bless.

Comment: Can only comment here. @noobiee please select one answer as valid since your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use an array of chars. Use a string and it will work like an array of chars. The problem with your current code is that cin only gets everything before an enter, so the moment you type the first character and push the enter button you terminate the cin. Instead you should use getline() which does not terminate with an enter.

You can go with

```
      #include "string"
      string name;
      getline(cin, name);
```

or use getline() in your current code.

Comment: i tried using getline but it didnt  output anything.                                                getline(cin,student[x].name);

Comment: @noobiee it should be in the form of getline(cin, stringname). student[x].name is not a valid argument. if your string is called student. then only put student in there. btw you don't really need an array. Just do it like my mane example. use a string and then use getline (cin, stringname). It will work like an array and you won't need the [x] part.